# Any way to contact a user on GitHub?

Tags: github

I'd like to contact a developer on GitHub to see how I can help out, etc. I don't see the option anywhere.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can contact a GitHub user by going to her/his user page (`https://github.com/[USERNAME]`) and on the left-hand side, you should see her/his email address if they have provided one. Also, make sure you are currently logged in, otherwise, it might not be visible to you).

Answer (score 56):

Check out the repository and look for their email address in the Git log.

Answer (score 35):

**This method worked in August 2022**

1. Copy and paste the next line into your browser (feel free to
   bookmark it): https://api.github.com/users/xxxxxxx/events/public.
2. Find the GitHub username for which you want the email: Replace the
   xxxxxxx in the URL with the person's GitHub username. Hit Enter.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for “email”.

Comment: Not working. That page just shows an empty array. (`[ ]`)

Comment: FYI unfortunately this only works if the user has made their email public. If they have not then the other options posted here are worth a shot.

Comment: This https://api.github.com/users/xxxxxxx/ is working link!

Comment: Yeah the email is `@users.noreply.github.com` so dead end.

Comment: @felwithe you might have to click on "Raw Data" to see the texts in the arrays

Answer (score 24):

I don't know about sending them a message directly, but if you post a comment in a discussion that they are involved in, then it will appear as a notification in their github account.

Answer (score 20):

If users are active on GitHub, you might be able to catch their email address from a commit log or open up an issue on a project they are working on.

If they are inactive however and don't have a visible email or repository there doesn't seem to be a direct way. I came up with this workaround that might be worth a try in extreme cases:

- create an empty repository
- add a README.md to it containing your message and include a reply email
- go to the `Settings` of that repository
- send the repository via `Transfer Ownership` to the user in question

This should produce a notification for the user and allow him to contact you.

In cases when a user account is completely dead and you just want to get rid of it so that you can use the name for your own projects, you can also contact support, they will remove dead accounts:

https://help.github.com/articles/name-squatting-policy/

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how long this has been in place, but now you can add `@username message_content` in a discussion and that user will be notified.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about where in the interface this can be done?

Comment: Probably any where you enter "comments" e.g. on an issue.

Comment: Just write "@user ping" in any of issue comments

Comment: "discussion" == **Issue** or **Pull Request** or any comment on a commit, etc.

Answer (score 9):

This question has [an answer at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686545/how-to-leave-a-message-for-github-com-user/12687679#12687679) by [nulltoken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335418/nulltoken).

> Although GitHub removed the private messaging feature, there's still an alternative.
>
> GitHub host git repositories. If the user you're willing to communicate with has ever committed some code, there are good chances you may reach your goal. Indeed, within each commit is stored some information about the author of the change or the one who accepted it.
>
> Provided you're really dying to exchange with user **user_test**
>
> - Display the public activity page of the user:
>   `https://github.com/user_test?tab=activity`
> - Search for an event stating **"user_test pushed to [branch] at
>   [repository]"**. There are usually good chances, he may have pushed one
>   of his own commits. Ensure this is the case by clicking on the "View
>   comparison..." link and make sure the user is listed as one of the
>   committers.
> - Clone on your local machine the repository he pushed to: `git clone https://github.com/..../repository.git`
> - Go to that directory `cd repository`
> - Checkout the branch he pushed to: `git checkout [branch]`
> - Display    the latest commits: `git log -50`
>
> As a committer/author, an email should be displayed along with the commit data.
>
> **Note:** Every warning related to unsolicited email should apply there. Do *not* spam.

Just code your own if you are better at it and have a fix or a change. GitHub is open source. Code on GitHub is free to change obviously.

Answer (score 4):

The method that best worked for me does not require to clone the repo.

I found the answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444770/2643104), who took it from [Chris Herron @ Sourcecon](https://www.sourcecon.com/how-to-find-almost-any-github-users-email-address-2-0/):

- Browse someone's commit history (Click commits which is next to    branch to see the whole commit history)
- Click the commit that with the person's username because there might    be so many of them
- Then you should see the web address has a hash concatenated to the    URL. Add .patch to this commit URL
- You will probably see the person's email address there

Example: [https://github.com/[username]/[reponame]/commit/[hash].patch](https://github.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Breponame%5D/commit/%5Bhash%5D.patch)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the current URL to see user events including email (January 2021):
https://api.github.com/users/username/events
(search the page for "email")

or just https://api.github.com/users/username if they made their mail public on their profile.

This is an update on Porcupine's answer:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107500/261901
(the /public version doesn't work anymore)

I would just write a comment below it, but i don't have the 50 reputation necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For a command-line adventure using a script I've modified:

1. Visit https://github.com/DaveJarvis/github-email
2. Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/github-email#wget) to install into `$HOME/bin`.
3. Set your GitHub [token](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/github-email#authenication-token).
4. Open a new terminal.
5. Run: `github-email username`

The script automates using GitHub's HTTP REST API to find email addresses associated with Git commit histories. The script will also look for the user's contact information from a few different sources. You could perform all the steps the script takes from within a web browser.

The key line from the script is to retrieve all commits against a particular repository (owned by the user whose email address is desired):

```
# Find all commits against the repository
$CMD -H "$PARAM_GITHUB_TOKEN" "$API_GITHUB/repos/$ARG_USERNAME/$ARG_REPOSITORY/commits" \
  | jq -r ".[] | .commit | .author | $NAME_FORMAT" 2>/dev/null \
  | sort \
  | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Open any commit he made in any repository. And you will some info like this

```
username committed on Dec 18, 2019, 1 parent 69b389d commit 4b87ccc patch diff
```

Where `patch` and `diff` are links, click the patch link and you will see commit info like this

```
From 4b87ccca84710991f0876d0c051e5e0ff223ac99 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: FirstName LastName <hisemail@example.com>
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2019 22:51:16 -0500
Subject: commit name
```

From here you can see his email address

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch Github API with a form too, here is an example: https://roneo.org/en/app/github-user-email-finder/

Note the limitations:

- only the last 6 months of activity are considered
- false positives may appear as authors of merged PR are added to the list