# Contacting another GitHub user not already in any discussions

Tags: github

Is there a canonical way to contact a GitHub user who doesn't appear to be involved in any discussions? For example, can you start a discussion on one of their projects to make a comment?

From [Anyway to contact a user on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29197/anyway-to-contact-a-user-on-github) I know I can alert the user by commenting on any discussion that they are involved in.

But the user I'm seeking to annoy does not appear to be in any discussions (either that, or I don't know how to find his list of discussions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's no canonical way to contact a user, github recently introduced a [Mention @anybody, they're notified](https://github.com/blog/821) feature.

> When you @mention a GitHub username anywhere in the context of an issue or pull request, that person is notified and subscribed to future updates.

You can also create a gist & mention him in the comment, thereby notifying the user.

Comment: Felt horribly kludgy, but took a shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

[Mentions](https://github.com/blog/821) (`@username`) are probably the appropriate way to notify a user in the context of a pull request or issue. To notify someone when I create a pull request or issue, I usually write `/cc @username` as a FYI.

To contact a GitHub user out of any pull request or issue context, I prefer emails. This should be pretty rare though.